# ディープコピーせずにインデックスをずらしただけの配列を作りたい

Tags: python

行数の多い CSV を読み込んで MySQL に流し込みたいです

CSV は１行目にヘッダが書かれていて２行目からを executemany に渡して
bulk insert したいです

results に以下のように CSV の 2 次元配列が入っているとして

```
[['col1', 'col2'],
 [1, 'a'],
 [2, 'b'],
  :
```

results.pop(0) とか results[1:] 
をすると index を 1 ずつずらした配列を生成するので前処理で時間とメモリを消費してしまいます

C でいう *p++ みたいなことがしたいですが python では不可能でしょうか？

CSVを読むときにヘッダだけ分離して読み込むっていう方法も考えたのですが
諸事情であまりやりたくありません

値を渡したいメソッドはこちらです
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor-executemany.html

よろしくお願いします

Comment: 関連？: [Can I create a “view” on a Python list?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3485475/5989200) -- Stack Overflow

Comment: 「index を 1 ずつずらした」から思い付いたのですが、iterator を使うのはどうでしょうか。具体的には `itresults = iter(results)` として、`next(itresults)` としてから `cursor.executemany(stmt, itresults)` とします。

Comment: ありがとうございます。メソッド側が iterator に対応してくれてたみたいでできました。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

コメントいただいた通り、イテレーターを使う方法

```
itresults = iter(results)
next(itresults)
cursor.executemany(stmt, itresults)
```

でうまく行きました